# Extract text using word VBA regex then save to a variable as string

Tags: regex, string, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create code in Word VBA that will automatically save (as PDF) and name a document based on it's content, which is in text and not fields.  Luckily the formatting is standardized and I already know how to save it.  I tested my regex elsewhere to make sure it pulls what I am looking for.  The trouble is I need to extract the matched statement, convert it to a string, and save it to an object (so I have something to pass on to the code where it names the document).

The part of the document I need to match is below, from the start of "Program" through the end of the line and looks like:

> Program: Program Name (abr)

and the regex I worked out for this is "Program:[^\n]"

The code I have so far is below, but I don't know how to execute the regex in the active document, convert the output to a string and save to an object:

```
Sub RegExProgram()

Dim regEx
Dim pattern As String

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = False
regEx.pattern = "Program\:[^\n]"

(missing code here)

End Sub
```

Any ideas are welcome, and I am sorry if this is simple and I am just overlooking something obvious.  This is my first VBA project, and most of the resources I can find suggest replacing using regex, not saving extracted text as string.  Thank you!

Comment: While that was a good description of how to create regular expressions, it did not address my largest problem... I do not want to replace text, I want to extract it and save it to an object as a string.  Also I am not using excel to work within cells or worksheets, I am using Word so when I use regEx.test() or regEx.Execute() I don't know where to reference.

Comment: I'm assuming that the "Program Name (abr)" part of your string will be different things depending on the document?

Comment: @Pat_Jones, yes it will be different.  I have tested the regex above using sample docs and an online regex tester, and that seems to work.  It grabs everything from "Program: ..." through the end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

<sup>You can find documentation for the `RegExp` class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62(v=vs.85).aspx).</sup>

```
Dim regEx as Object
Dim matchCollection As Object
Dim extractedString As String

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regEx
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Global = False    ' Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
  .Pattern = "Program: ([^\r]+)"  ' Word separates lines with CR (\r)
End With

' Pass the text of your document as the text to search through to regEx.Execute().
' For a quick test of this statement, pass "Program: Program Name (abr)"
set matchCollection = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)

' Extract the first submatch's (capture group's) value - 
' e.g., "Program Name (abr)" - and assign it to variable extractedString.
extractedString = matchCollection(0).SubMatches(0)
```

- I've modified your regex based on the assumption that you want to capture everything *after* `Program:` through the end of the line; your original regex would only have captured `Program:<space>`.

  - Enclosing `[^\r]+` (all chars. through the end of the line) in `(...)` defines a so-called *subexpression* (a.k.a. capture group), which allows selective extraction of only the substring of interest from what the overall pattern captures.
- The `.Execute()` method, to which you pass the string to search in, always returns a *collection* of matches (`Match` objects).
  Since the `.Global` property is set to `False` in your code, the output collection has (at most) *1* entry (at index `0`) in this case.
- If the regular expression has subexpressions (1 in our case), then *each* entry of the match collection has a nonempty `.SubMatches` collection, with one entry for each subexpression, but note that the `.SubMatches` entries are *strings*, not `Match` objects.
- [Match objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9k561zd(v=vs.85).aspx) have properties `.FirstIndex`, `.Length`, and `Value` (the captured string). Since the `.Value` property is the *default* property, it is sufficient to access the object itself, without needing to reference the `.Value` property (e.g., instead of the more verbose `matchCollection(0).Value` to access the captured string (in full), you can use shortcut `matchCollection(0)` (again, by contrast, `.SubMatches` entries are *strings* only).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for.  Can't wait to try it Monday morning.  Thanks @mklement0

Comment: Exactly what I needed, but finding one problem... It isn't stopping at the end of the line (or any of the other lines or carriage returns).  I pasted the variable extractedString into a message box to double check the output.  I know your regEx is right because I tested it in a tester.  Any ideas?  I made sure the escape character goes the right way and everything.  I am copying and pasting so you can see what I am using...        .pattern = "Program: ([^\n]+)"

Comment: Oops!  They are carriage returns and require \r not \n, but your code was perfect it was my mistake that made it not work.  Thanks!

Comment: @schradera: Glad to hear it worked; thanks for telling me that `\r` rather than `\n` is needed - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for a string that starts with "Program:" and want to go to the end of the line from there, you don't need a regular expression:

```
Public Sub ReadDocument()

Dim aLine As Paragraph
Dim aLineText As String

Dim start As Long

For Each aLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    aLineText = aLine.Range.Text
    start = InStr(aLineText, "Program:")

    If start > 0 Then
        my_str = Mid(aLineText, start)
    End If

Next aLine

End Sub
```

This reads through the document line by line, and stores your match in the variable "my_str" when it encounters a line that has the match.

Comment: While you don't _need_ the `RegExp` object in this simple case, why _wouldn't_ you use it, given that it offers more powerful matching when you need it,
makes for shorter code, and is probably faster, since you don't have to loop in VBA code?

Comment: All quite true, just giving the OP another option if it is desired, that's all.

Comment: Interesting.  I was excite to finally learn regex, it has been on my to to list for a while, but I like being able to look at things from different perspectives too.  Thanks @PatJones

Answer (score 2):

Lazier version:

```
a = Split(ActiveDocument.Range.Text, "Program:")
If UBound(a) > 0 Then 
    extractedString = Trim(Split(a(1), vbCr)(0))
End If
```

If I remember correctly, paragraphs in Word end with `vbCr` ( `\r` not `\n` )